# converting style css to scss

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, angular8

I am trying to convert my current angular 8 project style.css to sass but the compiler error

I have tried to manually change the "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"

I want to convert the style sheet can someone help me

Comment: Could you show the detailed error? Did you change to `src/style.scss` in your `angular.json` file?

Comment: yes when i did that it error in the console this => (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

Check your angular.json to see if these configuration exist

```
"schematics": {
   "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "style": "scss"
     }
    },
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/testssss",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": false,
        "assets": [
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
            "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
    },
```

Also make sure to change your css file to scss extension